# Unable to connect BlackBerry phone with Bluetooth SPP device

Tags: blackberry, bluetooth, spp

I am trying to connect to a bluetooth device from the blackberry 9900 phone using the following code;

```
public final class AppMainScreen extends MainScreen {
private BluetoothspInfo[] spInfo;
    private StreamConnection bConn;
    private DataInputStream diStream;
    private String text;

    public AppMainScreen() {

        spInfo = BluetoothSerialPort.getSerialPortInfo();

        try {
            bConn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(
                    spInfo[0].toString(), Connector.READ);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new TextScanner());
    }

    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

But its always throwing the exception `java.io.IOException: Unable to connect.` I am not able to get the full trace.
What is the problem here, can anybody please point me in the right direction.
I am using the BlackBerry Java on BlackBerry Eclipse Plugin with Platform version 4.5.